# console logs 'The provider id_provider is not a valid one'

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Trying to get head around when debugging a Viewer app. Chrome console shows 'The provider id_provider is not a valid one'. Any suggestion?
If options is like this:

> ```
>         var options = {
>             env: 'AutodeskProduction',                 
>             getAccessToken: getToken } 
>             }
>          function getToken () {
>             var response;
>             var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
>             xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
>             if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
>                 response = JSON.parse(
>                 xhr.responseText);
>                 return response.access_token;
>                }
> ```

if forcing 2.9,  'The provider id_provider is not a valid one'.

If forcing 2.7 or 2.8, not log but the viewer doesn't show up.

If no specified version, 'Warning : no access token is provided. Use built in token : YtTb8vRA4XQfTorjm9c8eVZJTYP6'.
it stops in Autodesk360App.js

> ```
>      var initialItem = app.getDefaultGeometry(geometryItems);
> ```

Chrome logs 'Uncaught TypeError: app.getDefaultGeometry is not a function'

If I directly feed token:

> ```
>       accessToken: 'MorPwhKARIS3VGIrcd3FrZSjsnOx5'
> ```

it works beautifully in 2.7,2.8 and 2.9. But if no version, it stops in Autodesk360App.js, the same as above.

Thank you!

Comment: can you add some details, like viewer version, if you're calling something more complex. This error should not happen on a standard workflow.

Comment: question has been edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you missing the **url** on the http request? Maybe something line:

```
function getToken() {
  var xmlHttp = null;
  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", '/yourTokenEndPoint', false);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  var response = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
  return response.access_token;
}
```

For the [Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/), it must be synchronous.

Comment: Thank you Augusto for addressing 'synchronous', then I shouldn't have used 'onreadystatechange'!